# Ansible/Jinja2 How to format a list into fields for my config file?

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I have the following and keep in mind I do not know how many ips will be in this incoming variable but I am starting with 2 for simplicity.

```
vars:
  host_ips: ['10.0.0.100', '10.0.0.200']
```

I'm trying to format them in a file using a template with Ansible.

```
- targets: ['10.0.0.100:9090', '10.0.0.200:9090']
```

What syntax in Jinja2 do I use to make the host ips look like the above targets line?  I KNOW I have to iterate for sure.

Comment: - targets: [{% for ip in host_ips %}'{{ ip }}:5051'{% endfor %}]

That got me a little closer the output is:

- targets: ['10.0.0.100:9090''10.0.0.200:9090']

I just need the comma in between them so I need to figure that out

Answer (score 10):

```
-targets: [{% for ip in host_ips %}'{{ ip }}:5051'{{ "," if not loop.last else "" }} {% endfor %}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-targets: [{% for ip in host_ips %}'{{ ip }}:5051',{% endfor %}]
```

test.yml playbook:

```
vars:
  host_ips: ['10.0.0.100', '10.0.0.200','10.0.0.300']
tasks:
  - debug: msg=[{% for ip in host_ips %}'{{ ip }}:5051',{% endfor %}]
```

ansible-playbook -i localhost test.yml

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "10.0.0.100:5051", 
        "10.0.0.200:5051", 
        "10.0.0.300:5051"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to struggle with Jinja2 loops here. All you need is to apply a transformation for the list elements (for example with [`map`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#map) and [`regex_replace`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#regular-expression-filters) filters):

```
host_ips | map('regex_replace', '^(.*)$', '\\1:9090')
```

---

With the above construct you can:

- use it to set a new variable in Ansible:

  ```
    - set_fact:
        targets: "{{ host_ips | map('regex_replace', '^(.*)$', '\\1:9090') | list }}"
  ```

or "*format them in a file using a template*" which per your request is a JSON representation of a list:

- With double quotes in the output:

  ```
    - targets: {{ host_ips | map('regex_replace', '^(.*)$', '\\1:9090') | list | to_json }}
  ```

procudes:

```
    - targets: ["10.0.0.100:9090", "10.0.0.200:9090"]
```

- If you really need single quotes in the output simply replace them:

  ```
    - targets: {{ host_ips | map('regex_replace', '^(.*)$', '\\1:9090') | list | to_json | regex_replace('"', '\'') }}
  ```

produces:

```
    - targets: ['10.0.0.100:9090', '10.0.0.200:9090']
```